# post-save signal doesn't get called in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-signals

Whenever a new User instance is created, I want to create a Profile instance linked to it.
To do this, I'm trying to use signals.

here's code from models.py:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender,**kwargs):
    print(sender)
```

And here's from view.py:

```
@api_view(["POST"])
def register(request):
  username = request.data.get("username")
  first_name = request.data.get("first_name")
  last_name = request.data.get("last_name")
  email = request.data.get("email")
  password1 = request.data.get("password1")
  password2 = request.data.get("password2")

  user = User.objects.create_user(username,email,password1)

  if user:
      user = authenticate(username=username, password=password1)

  if not user:
      return Response({"error": "Login failed"}, status=HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)

  token, _ = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
  return Response({"token": token.key})
```

However, nothing gets printed to my Terminal when a new User is created.

EDIT: I moved the function to signals.py and edited apps.py but it's still not working:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class AuthConfig(AppConfig):
  name = 'auth'
  verbose_name = 'Auth Application'

  def ready(self):
      from . import signals
```

and here's `__init__.py`:

```
default_app_config = 'auth.apps.AuthConfig'
```

Comment: What is the location of your create_user_profile function inside of your models.py

Comment: @iklinac Right below the Profile model class

Comment: @dpstart It must be either below User Model and not Profile Model, or (as I prefer) should be in separate listeners file linked appropriately through AppConfig

Comment: Can you show how I should link it through AppConfig?

Comment: Are you referring to the same `User` in your Signal and your view? Are you importing `from django.contrib.auth.models import User` in both or have you specified a custom `User` model in your `models.py`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit outdated answer, but is this what you were looking for?

From [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/signals/#connecting-receiver-functions):

> Where should this code live?
>
> Strictly speaking, signal handling and registration code can live
>   anywhere you like, although it’s recommended to avoid the
>   application’s root module and its models module to minimize
>   side-effects of importing code.
>
> In practice, signal handlers are usually defined in a signals
>   submodule of the application they relate to. Signal receivers are
>   connected in the ready() method of your application configuration
>   class. If you’re using the receiver() decorator, import the signals
>   submodule inside ready().

Answer (score -1):

Generally the issue is `signals.py` hasn't been imported, [you need to add it to your `AppConfig`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/signals/#connecting-receiver-functions) as mentioned in the comments:

```
# apps.py

# or whatever the class is called inside the app containing signals.py
class RegistrationConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'registration'

    # This is the piece you will need to add
    def ready(self):
        from . import signals
```

Comment: I did this but it's not working anyway (I edited the question)

Comment: Make sure in your settings.py file, you are installing the package using the apps.py config class, and not the module itself. This means

INSTALLED_APPS = ["module.apps.RegistrationConfig"]

Comment: This is not necessary. Also, your link to the Django docs doesn't say so.